# Passing php variable from this.php to that.php

Tags: php, html, web-services, variables

So I need to pass a variable from one php to another php page but I dont know how to do it. I got this piece of code "$realname= $row['name'];" that stores the real name of the person to display it in another page after they successfully login, but when I try to use $realname variable in the other page it wont display it. How can I make this posible??? thanks in advance

page one login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php

include 'functions.php';

if(loggedin())
{
header("Location: userarea.php");
exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
//get data
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];

    //validate
    if($username&&$password)
    {
        $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($login) == 1)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login))
            {

                $db_password = $row['password'];
                if($password == $db_password)
                   $loginok= TRUE;
                else
                   $loginok = FALSE;

                 if($loginok==TRUE)
                 { 

                                  $realname= $row['name'];

                                       if($rememberme == "on")
                        setcookie("username", $username, time() + 7200);
                    else if ($rememberme == "")
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;


                    header("Location: userarea.php");
                    exit();
                 }
                 else
                     die("Incorrect username or password. Please try again or contact your local admin.");
            }

        }die("Incorrect username or password. Please try again or contact your local admin.gdfgdfgdfg");
    }
    else
        die("Please enter a username and password.");

}

?>


<h>Welcome!</h>

    <form action="login.php" method="POST">

    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username"><p />

    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password"><p /  >  



    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme"> Remember me<br />

    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Page 2 userarea.php (as you can see I declared $realname variable but I cant use it)

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

include 'functions.php';


if(!loggedin())
{
header("Location: login.php");
exit();

}

echo "Hello $realname";

?>



<h>Access Granted! Yeiy! </h>
<a href="logout.php"> Log out </a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to read php documentation more, SESSIONS are there to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) are for:

> Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data.

page one login.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
$_SESSION['realname'] = $row['name'];
```

Page 2 userarea.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
echo "Hello $_SESSION['realname']";
```

Answer (score 0):

First pass `$_SESSION['var_name'];` on login page and then

start `session_start()` on the top of the userarea page and echo your session variable

```
echo $_SESSION['var_name'];
```